# Groupby for the specific type of record

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am little confused about a query. I have a posts table with the field {type}.type field has different values. Now the requirement is that, I want to fetch use groupBy {Date} for the specific type of post.

```
    Collection {#832 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => Post {#833 ▶}
    1 => Post {#834 ▶}
    2 => Post {#835 ▶}
    3 => Post {#836 ▶}
    4 => Post {#837 ▼
      Post: array:5 [▼
      0 => Post {#833 ▶}
      1 => Post {#834 ▶}
      2 => Post {#835 ▶}
      3 => Post {#836 ▶}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

in this first array 4th key is groupBy.
I hope you can understand my requirements 
Thanks In advance

Comment: Provide more information like the query you're using. Also try to explain it better

Comment: actually i want to fetch all records with all type and want to show all record in a separate array where type is friend as shown in the Question

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$type = "example"; //whatever a valid value for type would by, based on your code.
Post::where('type', $type)->groupBy('date')->get();
```

By placing the `where()` before the `groupBy()` you can filter results a bit more.

Comment: actually i want to fetch all records with all type and want to show all record in a separate array where type is friend as shown in the Question